# Miracles performed by Ram in Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, rama

In Ramayana, was Ram regarded as a deity and incarnation of Vishnu from the very beginning, or was he deified in subsequent editions of the epic?

Did anyone ask Ram to prove his divinity?

Did Ram perform any miracles in Ramayana?

Did Ram perform any miracles in Ramayana to prove his divinity?

Comment: To perform mircales is work of magicians. Divinity means staying as you are is divinity. Being steady minded and similing in all circumstances is divinity. 1st one is Ram. 2nd one is Krishna!

Comment: Hello, you have to add "Rama" tag

Comment: The link above does explain Rama's powers. However, if I compare Rama to Jesus, Moses, and Mohammed, they had to perform miracles because their own people did not believe that they were God (in the case of Jesus) and they were sent by God (in the cases of Moses and Mohammed). Is this because Rama was so powerful that it was evident that he was God, and no one questioned him?

Comment: It was a Puranic concept that depicted Sri Rama as the incarnation of God.  If we omit the interpolated episodes and read Valmiki Ramayana,  it will be evident that Sri Rama was depicted as human only ,who adhered to Dharma @DAN BHATT

Answer (score 1):

Ram never performed miracles to prove his divinity also his people never asked him to prove himself to be Divine in the entire Ramayana, 
But there are some miracles performed by him in Ramayana
One of them is when he frees ahaliya from her curse of being stoned just by touching her which is turning a stone statue back to real women

Comment: Your post is extremely confusing. Downvoted.